# Unable to see values in debug mode when mouse placed over local variables VS 2015

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I am unable to see the values of local variables in debug mode when mouse pointer placed over them or by adding `add watch` option in visual studio 2015. I am also getting the error

> Internal error in the expression evaluator

I have tried the following to fix the error

- Rebuilded the solution
- Restarted Visual studio
- Restarted My PC
- Set Debug - > Options -> Ticked Use Mange Compatibility mode
- Set Debug - > Options -> Ticked Use Native Compatibility mode
- Set Debug - > Options -> Use the legacy c# and vb expression
  evaluators (**Note***:When I enable this I can see that it works for some of the codes when debugging on a device, but not all.In the emulator it works for all the code, but in earlier version of visual studio (2013) it works both for emulator and device without setting anything in visual studio at all*)

  [image: screen shoat of issue]
  None of these solved the problem. How can i fix this ?

Comment: It may be a bug in VS2015, I have experienced this and have seen other posts about it

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report debugger bugs.  They'll have no use for that screenshot, you'll need to include a minimum repro project so they can reproduce it and get the bug fixed.

Comment: Are you running VS as administrator? I've found this solved problems in past the now I just do this by default

Comment: Yes! it did worked Thankzz!!!!. May be you should post this as an answer so that i can accept it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the visual studio in Administrator mode seems to solve the issue also I need to put a tick mark  on

> Set Debug - > Options -> Use the legacy c# and vb expression
>   evaluators

as well.

Answer (score 1):

This can occur when the Optimize code option is checked in Project Properties>Build

Comment: No, That is unchecked here.